# How to take user input of an index for a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to make it so that the user will input an index for a nested list that will then remove that specified element. For example, the user should input: `my_list[0][3]` and it will remove that element

This is what I've tried:

```
def nested_remove(L, x):
    if x in L:
        L.remove(x)
    else:
        for element in L:
            if type(element) is list:
                nested_remove(element, x)
my_list=[["A",0,0,0],["B",0,0,0],["C",0,0,0],["D",0,0,0]]
x=int(input("What would you like to remove?"))
nested_remove(my_list, x)
print(my_list)
```

I need it to identify the user input as an index, not an integer. The error I'm currently getting is:

```
value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'my_list[0][3]'
```

Comment: What do you expect `int` to do with an input of `'my_list[0][3]'`? It doesn't have any clue what that is and, appropriately, raises an error. You should parse out the indices of the supplied string and pass them to your function.

Answer (score 0):

So from your snippet, you are good to go with a single list (i.e. not nested). But, when it comes to nested list, you are facing the issue. The issue here is in you calling. While calling, from your output :-

`value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'my_list[0][3]'`

I believe you are passing `my_list[0][3]` as your input.
And you expect that, this will be evaluated and will return you the value that you want to remove from the list. And therefore, you expect, you will get an integer (as result of above evaluation), that's why the type conversion to `int`.

To be noted, an expression is evaluated, not the value. And, when we pass a value to `input()` interpreter doesn't accept it as expression, hence no evaluation. It just stores it as a string. so your `int` typecasting fails with above error as `my_list[0][3]` is not evaluated.

So I would suggest why don't you accept tuple of 2 elements, where the first element would specify the list number and the second element the index of the element in the list specified in 1st element.

```
def nested_remove(L, x):
    def _process_input(L,x):
      x = x.split(',')
      if len(x) == 1:
        k= int(x[0])
      else:
        k = (L[int(x[0])][int(x[1])])
        L = L[int(x[0])]

      return L,k

    L,x = _process_input(L,x)
    try:
      L.remove(int(x))
    except ValueError as e:
      print ("Value not present")

   print(L)
```

Here in above you pass an element when a single list is present, and a tuple (separated by comma) when nested list is present. The `_process_input()` method parses your input and returns you the value and list to be removed.

Now to run above code with nested list :-

```
>>> my_list=[["A",1,2,3],["B",4,5,6],["C",7,8,9],["D",10,11,12]]
>>> nested_remove(my_list, x)
What would you like to remove :-  3,1
[['A', 1, 2, 3], ['B', 4, 5, 6], ['C', 7, 8, 9], ['D', 11, 12]]
```

When a single list is present :-

```
>>> my_list = [34, 5, 76]
>>> nested_remove(my_list, x)
What would you like to remove :-  5
[34, 76]
```

Hope this helps